# Why does not a zeta zero counting function $N_0(T)$ behave exactly in a neighborhood that all violations of Gram's law are occurred?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Q: Why does not a zeta zero counting function, on the critical line, $N_0(T)=1+\frac{\vartheta(T)}{\pi}+\frac{\arg(\zeta(\frac12+i T))}{\pi}$ behave exactly in a neighborhood that all violations of Gram's law are occurred?

$N_0(T)=1-\frac{T\log(2\pi)}{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\log\Gamma(\frac12-i T)-\log(\zeta(\frac12+i T))+\log\left(\frac{\zeta(\frac12+i T)}{(2\pi)^{i t}\Gamma(\frac12-i T)}\right)\right)$,

$N_0'(T)=0$ and

$\int{N_0(T)}{dT}=T N_0(T)$,

where $N_0(t)$ is a differentiable and integrable form on the symbolic computation.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: What is reference for the fist definition of $N_0$? Could be wrong, but I am not sure it counts the zeros.

Comment: @reuns: The above graphs are $N_0(t)$ and $N(t)$ as the step function. The first graph $N_0(t)$ does not behave exactly in a neighborhood $\rho_{127}$. My question is "Why does this phenomenon occur?".

Comment: @joro: $N_0(T)=1+\frac{\vartheta(T)}{\pi}+\frac{\arg(\zeta(\frac12+i T))}{\pi}$ ref. http://www.aimath.org/WWN/rh/articles/html/71a/

Comment: @SangkyuKim Thanks. I don't see theta at this link.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Can you define explicitly what you (think) are using and what you want to know ? @joro A clear definition of $N(t) = \#\{ \rho, Im(\rho) \in (0, t)\}$ is [there](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_zêta_de_Riemann#La_fonction_S.28T.29)

Comment: @reuns I added a proof of $N_0(T)$ in the above picture to avoid confusions. I used the symbolic computation of Mathematica 11.

Comment: Of course we can't decode your mathematica code. What is special in it ? Use latex.

Comment: At imaginary part Gram point g_n zeta is real and arg vanishes. This means $N_0(g_n)=1+n$ which is related to Gram's law.

Comment: @joro Gram points are defined as those (increasing) $g_n$ such that $\frac{\arg \zeta(1/2+ig_n)}{\pi}  \in \mathbb{Z}$ which means $\frac{\vartheta(g_n)}{\pi} = n$ and $N_0(g_n) = 1+n+\frac{\arg \zeta(1/2+ig_n)}{\pi}$

Comment: @reuns Isn't zeta purely real at $\zeta(1/2+ig_n)$ because of the formula with Siegel Z and theta? If it is purely real then arg() vanishes.

Comment: @reuns Isn't taking the correct branch of arg() a big issue? Paper defines function $S(t)=\frac{\arg \zeta(1/2+i t)}{\pi}$ and it isn't bounded by the principal branch.

Comment: @joro Did you read what I wrote ? Yes of course everything depends on how you define $\arg\ F(s)$. Here if $t$ is not the imaginary part of a zero then $ \log \zeta(s)$ is analytic around $\Im(s) = t$. This is how we define the **principal branch** of $ \log \zeta(s)$ analytic on $\Re(s) > 1$ and on almost every horizontal line, and how we set $\arg \zeta(1/2+it) = \Im \log \zeta(1/2+it)$ which is **not** in $[-\pi,\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica does not perform the correct analytic extension of $\arg(\zeta(\frac12+i T))$ which I discovered through the related question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037391 and the answer posted by @reuns at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037551. I believe the question I posted at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/240745/47171 also provides some insight.

Answer (score 0):

I think the claim $N_0(T)=1+\frac{\vartheta(T)}{\pi}+\frac{\arg(\zeta(\frac12+i T))}{\pi}$ which also appears in other papers is false.

Let $g_n$ denote the n-th [Gram point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Gram_points). Then $\zeta(1/2 + i g_n)$ is purely real and the argument in the last term vanishes. By the relation of theta and Gram points we have $N_0(g_n)=1+n$ which is essentially the Gram's law which is known to be false.

The first counterexample is at $T=g_{126}$.

Comment: $\arg \zeta(1/2+it)$ (as well as $\arg \Gamma(1/4+it/2)$) is defined by continuous variation along $2 \to 2+it \to 1/2+it$. The claim $$N(T)= \# \{ \rho,\Im(\rho) \in (0,T)\} = 1+\frac{\vartheta(T)}{\pi}+\frac{\arg(\zeta(\frac12+i T))}{\pi}, \qquad \vartheta(T) = \arg \Gamma(1/4+it/2)-\frac{\log(\pi)t}{2}$$ is **true** and is proven [there](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_fonction_S.28T.29)